# RunOnce key which starts elevated .ps1 file

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, windows-registry

so for few days I'm working on the automation script in powershell which starts elevated -> changes pc name -> creates the RunOnce reg file with this line as Value (program changes it automaticaly accordingly to file location) `"Powershell.exe -executionPolicy Unrestricted -file " + [string]$path + "\PCSetup.ps1 -check n"` -> restart pc. Afterwards it should automaticly start the app and continue elevated.
From what I understand the reg key executes CMD and paste the string specified in Value (which looks like this `Powershell.exe -executionPolicy Unrestricted -file C:\Users\user\Desktop\PCSetup.ps1 -check n` )

now, I know that the saved cmdlet works if run in elevated cmd but not normal cmd (or wathever program is used by the reg file), but how to elevate it automaticly in the reg file? I also tried with creating and registring new instance in task scheduler but can not pass variable to set file (with the relative path) to execute.

As extra info:
-check option is to execute the same script and automaticly skip renaming part of the program

i tried also with -command instead of -file

i tried also with -verb RunAs but it throws an error (1 of flags for me why it run the key in cmd)

i tried to look for this in many possible ways of approach, but workflow for powershell won't work as it's just for servers, sript ill be executed also on normal computers and from a local storage/removable device and other locations

i tried also to create an additional key wchich forces cmd to run as admin

Comment: What makes you think that CMD has anything to do with processing these keys?  Where will the application added to the RunOnce key get it's credentials from?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem is that your program is run as normal user whereas you want it to be run as elevated.

As you should know, UAC (User Account Control) prevent program to be run with elevated rights without asking the user before.

Here are some way to make your program run as elevated user:

- Use the RunOnce key located in HKLM instead of HKCU : it should start the program at the computer startup, with an elevated account not restricted by UAC.
- Logging with "Administrator" should run the script with elevation. Default Administrator account is not restricted by UAC
- Create a service or an elevated scheduled task, and make your RunOnce command run this task or service.
- Disable UAC on computers (**Not recommended for security purpose**)

Comment: Unfortunately HKLM instead of HKCU with the UAC disabled and an Administrator session does not work for me. I will give a try to a scheduled task...

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make this work with **RunOnce** or **RunOnceEx**.
However, the scheduled task works for me.

Working principal:
PowerShell process --> **Start-Process** cmdlet with the **RunAs** verb --> the final script to run

In the example below, you can:

- replace the **$PSCommandPath** variable (which makes the script run itself again) with the path to your script
- replace the **AtLogon** trigger parameter with **AtStartup**
- set the **-WindowsStyle** parameter value to **Hidden**, **Minimized** or **Maximized**

Furthermore, once you are comfortable with what you get, you can:

- replace the **UserId** principal with **"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"**
- Set the **LogonType** parameter as **ServiceAccount** to make it run as a hidden background process

---

```
$GlobalParameters = @{}
$GlobalParameters.Add('TaskPath', '\')
$GlobalParameters.Add('TaskName', 'MyTask')
$GlobalParameters.Add('Description', 'MyTask description')

#region Action
$PowerShell = 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
$ArgumentList = '-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit -File {0}' -f $PSCommandPath
$Command = "& Start-Process -FilePath '{0}' -WindowStyle Normal -Wait -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '{1}'" -f $PowerShell, $ArgumentList
$CommandLine = '-NoExit -WindowStyle Normal -Command "{0}"' -f $Command

$Parameters = @{
    Execute  = $PowerShell
    Argument = $CommandLine
}
$ScheduledTaskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction @Parameters
$GlobalParameters.Add('Action', $ScheduledTaskAction)
#endregion Action

#region Trigger
$Parameters = @{AtLogOn = $true }
$ScheduledTaskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger @Parameters
$GlobalParameters.Add('Trigger', $ScheduledTaskTrigger)
#endregion Trigger

#region Principal
$Parameters = @{
    UserId    = $env:USERNAME
    LogonType = 'Interactive'
    RunLevel  = 'Highest'
}
$ScheduledTaskPrincipal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal @Parameters
$GlobalParameters.Add('Principal', $ScheduledTaskPrincipal)
#endregion Principal

Register-ScheduledTask @GlobalParameters
```